# Telerik grid tabstrip remains disable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-grid

We had a application in `MVC 3` that was working fine.But now we have converted that into `MVC 4` .But now the tabs in grid are not `working/opening`. When tab is clicked it displays

`#TabStripEdit-3` in `URL`. `3 means 3rd tab is clicked`. It just showed in URL and remain at `first tab`.

I have searched it lot. But can getting the answer.Kindly help.Thanks in advance.I had posted the question yesterday but no one answered me. Thats y posting again because its high priority task for me.